# How we can return location header with StatusCodeResult 202 accepted response?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

We are using StatusCodeResult for 202 accepted response from API, but also need to return location header with this. How can we achieve this? Here is our current code:

```
response = new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Accepted,this);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
response.Headers.Location = Request.RequestUri;
```

Comment: Sorry, I wrote CreateErrorResponse in my first version by mistake.

Comment: No worries, thanks for your reply, actually our action method's return type is IHttpActionResult

Comment: thanks @Isma, its working fine now after casting the response ResponseMessage(response);

Comment: Cool, I edited the question to reflect that. I also simplified it a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom `IHttpActionResult` implementation where you set the header:

```
public class StatusCodeWithLocationResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly StatusCodeResult _result;
    private readonly Uri _location;

    public StatusCodeWithLocationResult(StatusCodeResult result, Uri location)
    {
        _result = result;
        _location = location;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await _result.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        response.Headers.Location = _location;
        return response;
    }
}
```

And then use it:

```
return new StatusCodeWithLocationResult(StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Accepted), myUri);
```